# Broken Fonts problem with Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: fonts

Upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.
With 11.10, I had broken fonts. I hoped to get rid of these broken  fonts with 12.04 but problem has worsened. 
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your font cache is probably messed up. Try clearing it.

To do the same, switch to tty1 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run:

```
$ sudo pkill -9 lightdm  # or whatever your desktop manager is
$ rm ~/.fontconfig/*
$ sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
```

You may want to reinstall font-packages `fonts-*` and `ttf-*` at this point:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | awk -F" " '/ttf-/ {print $2} /fonts-/ {print $2}' | while read line; do apt-get purge -y $line && apt-get install $line -y; done
```

Finally, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to reboot.

Comment: For some reason running the `dpkg` command removed all fonts but did not reinstall them and I was left with all fonts missing on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with the [code in (2)](https://askubuntu.com/a/136858/22949), here's my edited version:

```
sudo su
```

then

```
dpkg -l | awk -F" " '/ttf-/ {print $2} /fonts-/ {print $2}' | while read line; do apt-get purge -y $line && apt-get install $line -y; done
```

(added the -y)