# Broken fonts in Unity (they became thinner)

Tags: unity, fonts

Today, my Ubuntu 14.04 froze after suspending, so I had to hard-reboot it. When it rebooted, the fonts in the system changed from:

[image: good fonts]

to:

[image: bad fonts]

I hope you can see the difference. The latter are "thinner". Also it seems the fonts in text fields changed to monospace (?):

[image: fonts mono]

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136835/broken-fonts-problem-with-ubuntu-11-10) to no avail. How to fix the font settings?

Comment: Try ```fc-cache``` -rv in the terminal (source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/577999/ubuntu-14-nautilus-font-is-wrong).